Psexec run command on remote host as SYSTEM
Can PSEXEC be run as SYSTEM on remote host?
Even though -u -p values are provided, it is returning "Access is denied".
As local administrator, I started a cmd session as SYSTEM. Then I ran a remote command on remote computer, it returned  "Access denied". I can access admin$ share on remote computer and PSexec command works as local admin.

anyone who could help understanding what could be the issue .
